# JavaScript hasOwnProperty vs typeof

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

I've searched a lot on Google but couldn't found where I was looking for:

[Benefit of using Object.hasOwnProperty vs testing if Property is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17150396/benefit-of-using-object-hasownproperty-vs-testing-if-property-is-undefined)

[jsperf speedtest](http://jsperf.com/hasownproperty-vs-in-vs-undefined/12)

[How to determine if Native JavaScript Object has a Property/Method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595766/how-to-determine-if-native-javascript-object-has-a-property-method)

.. and a lot of other websites, but this is not where I am looking for. My real question is:

**Why does `hasOwnProperty` not find a method in his super class(prototype)? And why does somebody even use `hasOwnProperty`? It's much slower than `typeof` and it doesn't work if you are working with inheritance.**

.. second question:

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595766/how-to-determine-if-native-javascript-object-has-a-property-method) question Barney answers that you have to use `if ('property' in objectVar)` to check if a property exists, but doesn't explain why. Does someone knows why you would use this structure?

```
var objA = function(){};

objA.prototype.alertMessage = function(){
        return 'Hello A';
};

var objB = function(){
    this.hello = function(){
        return 'hello';
    };
};

// Inheritance
objB.prototype  = Object.create(objA.prototype);
objB.prototype.constructor = objA;

var test = new objB();

if (test.hasOwnProperty("alertMessage")){
    console.log("hasOwnProperty: " + test.alertMessage());
}

if (typeof test.alertMessage === "function"){
    console.log("typeof: " + test.alertMessage());
}

if (test.hasOwnProperty("hello")){
    console.log("hasOwnProperty: " + test.hello());
}

if (typeof test.hello === "function"){
    console.log("typeof: " + test.hello());
}
```

[Check out the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GuyT/8wy4so8m/)

Comment: `typeof` and `hasOwnProperty` are not related. The `in` operator is used to check for properties in the prototype chain, while `hasOwnProperty` checks only directly on that object. If you care about performance with `typeof`/`hasOwnProperty`, the fastest way is probably to simply use the evaluated value (since `undefined` evaluates to `false`), e.g. `if(test.alertMessage)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a number of reasons why one uses (and in some cases *has* to use) `hasOwnProperty`, and why its behavior is what it is:

- As the name suggests, `hasOwnProperty` checks if the object on which you test ***owns*** a property with a given name. If it has inherited a method/property from another object (its prototype), then the owner of that property is not the object, but its prototype. Therefore, the object doesn't have its own property called X
- `typeof` will work most of the time, but an object can look like this: `var o = {foo: undefined}`. Using `typeof` on `o.foo` will yield `"undefined"`, of course, but the object does own a property called `foo`
- using `if ('properyname' in object)` is a workaround, that combines the best of both worlds: in case of `o = {foo: undefined};` it *will* evaluate to true, without the overhead of a lookup for the `hasOwnPropery` method (which is a property of `Object.prototype`), or a function call with context binding and all that. It will also find properties in the prototype chain

So consider these examples:

```
var o = {foo: undefined,
    toString: undefined};//overwrite inherited method
console.log(typeof o.foo);//undefined
console.log(typeof o.toString);//undefined
console.log(o.hasOwnProperty('toString'));//true
delete(o.toString);
console.log(typeof o.toString);//function
if ('valueOf' in o)
    console.log(o.valueOf === Object.prototype.valueOf);//true
if ('foo' in o)
    console.log(o.foo);//undefined
```

Another important thing to note is that your statement about `hasOwnProperty` not working when dealing with inheritance is just plain *wrong*. Every object you use in JS inherits from at least one prototype. It is important to realize, understand and respect this. If you loop over an object, it is recommended to make sure you're actually iterating over the properties that belong to the object itself. Hence, this is not uncommon to see:

```
for (p in obj)
{
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p))
        //process property
}
```

This is to avoid having code that iterates over all properties in the prototype chain, an possibly mucking up the super object

```
if (!Object.prototype.hasProperty)
{//dirty check ;-P
    Object.prototype.hasProperty = (function(OP)
    {
        return function(name)
        {
            //typeof for speed: if value is not undefined, return true
            if (typeof this[name] !== 'undefined' || this.hasOwnProperty(name))
                return true;
            if (this === OP)//we've just checked the Object.prototype, found nothing, so return false
                return false;
            return Object.getPrototypeOf(this).hasProperty(name);//check prototype
        };
    }(Object.prototype));//OP is object prototype
}
```

Comment: Thank you to clarify this! The first point is clear, but it would make more sense if they would add a `hasProperty` method ;) The rest of you answer seems fine and I wasn't aware of the `undefined` 'trick'. Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: @GuyT: you could implement a `hasProperty` method, that uses `Object.getPrototypeOf` to traverse through the prototype chain, until `hasOwnProperty` returns true, or `false` at the `Object.prototype` level

Comment: Hmm.. that seems a nice implementation! I will check it out. Thanks.

Comment: @GuyT: Added a possible implementation of `hasProperty` to my answer